# Including text files to embed with Cabal

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, template-haskell

I've got a library I'm building that includes a few very large strings using Template Haskell and file-embed.

I'm wondering, how do I ensure these files are included when I run Cabal dist?

The are all in a folder called core, but some are within subdirectories of core.

Comment: Does this help? http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/adding-data-files-using-cabal.html?m=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cabal has an `extra-source-files` field precisely for these kinds of scenarios:

```
Extra-source-files: relative/path/to/my/embedded-file.txt
```

Quoting the [Cabal User Guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#package-properties):

> **extra-source-files**: *filename list*
>
> A list of additional files to be included in source distributions built with **setup sdist**.
>
> As with`data-files`it can use a limited form of wildcards in file names.

Comment: @jmte It supports a limited form of wildcards, so you can use e.g. `extra-source-files: data/*.tpl`.